# Qt slot argument is corrupted

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

The original code is to big to be posted here. Basically, I'm doing this:

```
class MySuperClass 
{
    QThread thread;
    MyClass myObject;

    MySuperClass() 
    {

        connect( this, &MySuperClass::onKill, &myObject, &MyClass::stop );

        connect( &thread, &QThread::started, &myObject, &MyClass::loop );
        connect(&myObject, &MyClass::finished, &thread, &QThread::quit );

        myObject.moveToThread( &thread );

        qRegisterMetaType<uint16_t>("uint32_t");

        connect( this, &MySuperClass::changed, &myObject, &MyClass::onChange );
    }

    void do()
    {
        emit changed(0);
    }
}
```

'onKill - stop' signal/slot have no parameters and work fine. No problem here.

Problem is 'changed - onChange' pair. They have one parameter of type uint32_t (which I have registered).

When I call method `do` of MySuperClass from the main thread the signal is emitted, the slot onChange is called but it's parameter is not 0!
It's some big number like 3043426304.

The funny part is: if I change connection type to DirectConnection - parameter is zero; if I change connection type to QueuedConnection - parameter is zero too! How can this be? Isn't AutoConnection either Queued or Direct?

I'm very puzzled by this. First of all: how stack allocated integer type parameter may be corrupted like that? I'd understand if it was something heap-allocated or used in multiple threads.

My second question is: how should I do this connection properly? Does the order of connect and moveToThread matter?

Comment: There is something strange: qRegisterMetaType<uint16_t>("uint32_t"); shouldn't that be qRegisterMetaType<uint32_t>("uint32_t");

Comment: ChrisG has probably pointed out your issue (+1 here). However, you could use quint32 (its interchangeable with uint32_t) but it is pre-registered so you can avoid having to register it and making hard to spot mistakes : )

Comment: @ChrisG riiight, that's very silly of me! Stupid copy-pasting error. I didn't notice that 3043426304 has zeros in two least significant bits. Thank you! Can you make your comment an answer so I could accept it? (Although I'm still interested about ordering of moveToThread and connect calls).

Comment: @code_fodder i really don't understand why everybody must create there own typedef for fixed length types. There are quint32 in Qt, guint32 in Glib, SINT32 in uC/OS - why bother if there are _standart_ typedefs?

Comment: @Amomum well, its just a Qt thing such that you get a "registered for free" type. But I whole heartedly agree with you I always use uint16_t everywhere. But in Qt you get a bit less hastle when using its built in types.

Comment: *i really don't understand why everybody must create there own typedef*, Qt does this for multi-platform reasons. The standard ones are not necessarily defined: [*These typedefs are not defined if no types with such characteristics exist*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/). Qt made their own to make sure you can use them on all platforms that are supported by Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 is answered by Chris. For question 2 (I did not see that the first time around)...

This is how to setup an object running in a seperate thread:

```
// Create the myObject object in its own thread
QThread* myThread= new QThread(); // you can assign `this` as parent if you want...
MyObject* myObject= new MyObject(0); // Assign no parent here (for QObject)
QObject::connect(myThread, &QThread::started, myObject, &MyObject::run, Qt::QueuedConnection);
myObject->moveToThread(myThread);
myThread->start();
```

You mostly have it correct. I think you are missing the "myThread->start()" function to kick the thread off. In your object creation its important to know that any dynamic allocations will be created in the parent thread space since the constructor runs before you move it to the thread. So its best to instantiate any objects you need inside the run() slot.

Any interaction with object once you start the thread should be via slots/signals.

Once you start the thread, it will emit started and your run() slot will be called.

The order of connect and moveToThread does not matter so long as you do all this before you call `myThread->start()`

**Note**

This is good for starting up a thread. There are some rules that may help you terminating the thread cleanly as well... but that's probably going off-topic

Comment: I start the thread in a separate function so I forgot to include it in pseudocode.

Comment: @Amomum ah ok, fair enough : )   ... Then I don't think you should be having any issues. What problem are you having with your thread?

Comment: @Amomum its also worth noting that your connection type (default to auto) will mean that your signals are Qt::QueuedConnection once you have moved your object to a different thread (whereas before the move they will be direct connection)... in my example I prefer always use queued connection unless I have a reason to use direct

Comment: Chris and you have already solved all my problems, for which I thank you :)